# How to restrict user from copying YouTube video link, from my android application

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I an playing YouTube video in my android application using "PierfrancescoSoffritti" github library. It is working completely fine, The only issue is I don't want user to copy the video link. While video is been played, there appears settings option, from where where user can change playback speed, quality which is my requirement, but along with that user can also copy video link. How to restrict that?

I have made custom player, but in that video quality option is not supported.

While using youtube player library(without custom UI) I tried Clipboard manager also to override the copied data, but some how its not working for link

Comment: As far as I know, you'll need to sacrifice the option for video quality if you want to restrict users from copying the video link. Alternatively, you can use Exoplayer and 
the android-youtubeExtractor library to create your video player with almost whatever feature you want. Although when I tried it, my video used to lag a lot. So you may need to apply some tricks there.